# Need to play video files inside an Angular app

Tags: angular

I must upload some videos into an Angular application (MEAN)
Is there a standard method?
I have .mp4 files, and I need to put them into some components.  Is doing a video basically just like doing an image?

Answer (score 3):

> I must upload some videos into an Angular application (MEAN) Is there a standard method?

There is no ***"special top secret CIA method"*** to do so.

All you need is to store the video files in a specific directory or use cloud storage options like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/).

Next you get the link pointing to the video file and embed it using HTML5.

```
<embed src="example.mpeg" autostart="false" height="30" width="144" />
```

Also, you can upload to YouTube and embedding the video using embed tag

```
<iframe  width="425" height="344" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/F9Bo89m2f6g" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You can learn more [here](https://tutorialehtml.com/en/html-tutorial-embed-video/)

**For Angular** support you might need to do a few more things, you have to sanitize the URL first.

import `DomSanitizer` to use it.

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Get hold of `DomSanitizer` and  sanitize the link.

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){
   let videoURL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KT2asqA1J8";
   this.safeURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(videoURL);
}
```

Then bind the value safeUrl to iframe in your component file.

```
<iframe [src]='safeURL' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```